# Using JsonPath how can I get the inner value of these json objects

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Say I have some json like this that I am parsing with `JsonPath`:

```
{
  A: {key: "1"}
  B: {key: "1"}
  C: {key: "1"}
  D: {key: "1"}
  E: {key: "1"}
}
```

or

```
{
  A: {key: "7"}
  B: {key: "7"}
  E: {key: "7"}
  G: {key: "7"}
}
```

A, B, C, D, E, ..., etc can be any tag and are not regularly named. However, `key` always has the same value in each of the objects. Using a `JsonPath` query how can I get the value of `key`? To be clear, the input should be that json and the output should be a single string containing the value of `key`

Comment: To clarify - if for example the first json is passed as input, the method should return "1"?

Comment: Yes, and the second json should return `7`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$..key`. This will return a `List` of values.
Then we need to use 'Stream API` to get an element out of it.

```
List<?> result = JsonPath.parse(s1)
                      .read("$..key", List.class);

result.stream()
      .findAny()
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```